# Select all text in HeadlessUI combobox after selecting an item?

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I'm trying to select all the text in the underlying input control after selecting an item with the HeadlessUI combobox. Following the example over at [HeadlessUI](https://headlessui.com/react/combobox) I've done the following modifications:

1. Added a ref to the input element,
2. Selecting the text in the input element from the onChange() event for the combobox.

```
import { Fragment, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { Combobox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon, ChevronUpDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'

const people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Wade Cooper' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Arlene Mccoy' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Devon Webb' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Tom Cook' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Tanya Fox' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Hellen Schmidt' },
]

export default function Example() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[0])
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const filteredPeople =
    query === ''
      ? people
      : people.filter((person) =>
          person.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace(/\s+/g, '')
            .includes(query.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
        )

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-16 w-72">
      <Combobox value={selected} onChange={(value) => {
          setSelected(value);
          if (inputRef.current) {
            // Why isn't this selecting the text in the input? 
            inputRef.current.select();
          }
        }}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <div className="relative w-full cursor-default overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-teal-300 sm:text-sm">
            <Combobox.Input
              className="w-full border-none py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:ring-0"
              displayValue={(person) => person.name}
              onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
              ref={inputRef}
            />
            <Combobox.Button className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
              <ChevronUpDownIcon
                className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </Combobox.Button>
          </div>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
            afterLeave={() => setQuery('')}
          >
            <Combobox.Options className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {filteredPeople.length === 0 && query !== '' ? (
                <div className="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 px-4 text-gray-700">
                  Nothing found.
                </div>
              ) : (
                filteredPeople.map((person) => (
                  <Combobox.Option
                    key={person.id}
                    className={({ active }) =>
                      `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                        active ? 'bg-teal-600 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                      }`
                    }
                    value={person}
                  >
                    {({ selected, active }) => (
                      <>
                        <span
                          className={`block truncate ${
                            selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                          }`}
                        >
                          {person.name}
                        </span>
                        {selected ? (
                          <span
                            className={`absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 ${
                              active ? 'text-white' : 'text-teal-600'
                            }`}
                          >
                            <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                          </span>
                        ) : null}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Combobox.Option>
                ))
              )}
            </Combobox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Combobox>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the setter inside your onChange handler with `flushSync`:

```
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";
.
.
.
<Combobox value={selected} onChange={(value) => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setSelected(value);
  })
  if (inputRef.current) {
     inputRef.current.focus();
     inputRef.current.select();
  }
}}>
```

Reference: https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#flushing-state-updates-synchronously-with-flush-sync

Comment: You could also try wrapping the imperative code in a `setTimeout` with a timeout of 0:
`setTimeout(() => inputRef?.current?.select(), 0);`

Comment: Thanks! It worked without having to set the timeout. And thank you for the reference to flushing state. :)